# How to change the variable being assigned via condition?

Tags: php, variables, conditional-statements

I want to change the variable being assigned based on condition, and I can seem to get it working.

```
$condition = false;

($condition !== false ? $array[1][$condition] : $array[1]) = 'Test';
```

In this example, if $condition isn't false, I want to assign the string "Test" to $array[1][$condition]. Otherwise, assign it to $array[1]

I can easily do this like this:

```
if ($condition !== false) {
    $array[1][$condition] = 'Test'; }
else {
    $array[1] = 'Test'; }
```

But due to the nature of the code this can get quite cluttered, which is why I wish for it to be an inline conditional statement.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Go with the full if statement. It's better, especially since the ternary operator is sort of broken in PHP.

Comment: `!== false` is unnecessary... `if ($condition) {` is all you need.  Since you're not conditionally updating one variable the `? :` syntax isn't going to work.

Comment: Fasco, thanks. I understand that the !== is unnecessary, but I've always used it since it's faster and easier to read what's going on. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$condition !== false ? $array[1][$condition] = "Test" : $array[1] = "Test";
```

Comment: this is not what the OP wants.

Comment: Actually, this seems to be the best way unless there are better solutions. If I assign 'Test' to a variable, I can use:
    $condition !== false ? $array[1][$condition] = $var : $array[1] = $var;

Answer (score 1):

```
$condition = false;

$array[1][$condition] = ($condition !== false ? 'Test' : $array[1]);
```

Comment: winner winner, chicken dinner!

Comment: This will not work. If condition is false, it doesn't give the desired answer.

Answer (score 0):

[The result of the ternary operator is not a reference](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53117), so you can't use it as the left-hand side of an assignment.

You might be able to use variable variables and references, but this might just add complexity without providing any real benefit.

Something like this:

```
$a =& $array[1];
$b =& $array[1][$condition];

$var = ($condition !== false ? 'b' : 'a');
$$var = 'Test';
```